Options for emitting arbitrary attributes in react
I'm writing a design tool that first parses a piece of html and then re-renders it with a tree of React components like this:
const ArtboardNode = function ({ node }) {
      const elementProps = node.attributes.toJSON();

      const children = node.hasChildren
        ? node.children.map((n) => <ArtboardNode key={n.id} node={n} />)
        : undefined;

      return React.createElement(node.tagName, elementProps, children);
}

Here, node is a custom object already (corresponding to an HTMLElement) that I'm using as an intermediate representation for the document.
This is already working somewhat, but there are some issues:

React gives runtime warnings on attribute names that do not match the respective property/React names (class vs className, etc.).
React gives a runtime error when a style attribute is present, as it doesn't like a string for that one. There may be other attributes with such a problem.

Obviously I could now start to hack around these issues, such as manually building a name mapping and add special handing for some special cases such as style.
I'm asking if somebody either knows how to deal with points 1+2 better or has a better approach in general. I also considered not using React for this part at all, but I'd like to have some intermediate state for the editor to work on and the way it's already set up it would be very easy to implement things like undo operations.

are you using typescript? My idea is that you could specified node event more by passing the "original" node through that custom type where you use the keyvalue (like className) for when using createElement (not exactly a hack but more like a trick that looks "clean")?

@Richard Not using typescript so far, and what I'm doing here is entirely dynamic. There can be any attributes, including non-standard ones. Not quite sure what you are proposing (I'm already using a custom "type" - the attributes property isn't the one on HTMLElement.

Firstly, this is an interesting requirement but one that is not without premise, but it is also somewhat unusual since it implies the consuming code is not React-aware or explicitly can not or does not care about that. Is there more to your use case that means using React is useful to you? Perhaps some interaction with existing react state or context, or other components?

"but I'd like to have some intermediate state for the editor to work on and the way it's already set up it would be very easy to implement things like undo operations.". Sorry you did state this. Let me think and formulate an answer

There are essentially two choices, which are very different:
Option One - React "raw DOM" escape hatch
This is somewhat similar to "not using React" in the sense that it makes the injected DOM not directly subject to React's VDOM algo but keeps the injection logic colocated with your React component.
Using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, you can have React inject DOM nodes constructed from a string. Those DOM nodes are then driven by that string.
This isn't the whole solution for you since you have only an object representation of the HTML element at hand, not a whole HTML string ready to inject. You could construct such a thing just to use with dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but that seems obtuse.
However, DOM nodes created with dangerouslySetInnerHTML have the unique property of not being touched by React's re-render process unless the string in the __html property of the object passed to dangerouslySetInnerHTML changes, or the element that dangerouslySetInnerHTML is declared on unmounts. This means the DOM elements created by it, unlike the norm in React, can be manipulated by imperative direct DOM calls, and you don't fundamentally violate React's internal model in the process. It is, however, esoteric to do something like his.
Practically, you use dangerouslySetInnerHTML just to create an empty container. You then use the raw DOM API to append to it.
import React, { useId, useLayoutEffect } from "react";

const ArtboardNode = function ({ node }) {
  const id = useId();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const createDomEl = (currentNode, parentEl) => {
      const el = document.createElement(currentNode.tagName);
      Object.entries(currentNode.attributes).forEach(([name, val]) =>
        el.setAttribute(name, val),
      );

      parentEl.appendChild(el);

      if (currentNode.hasChildren) {
        currentNode.children.forEach((child) => createDomEl(child, el));
      }
    };

    createDomEl(node, document.getElementById(id));
  }, [node, id]);

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `<div id="${id}"></div>` }} />;
};


I have not tested this, but as pseudo code it would achieve converting the node structure to DOM nodes without interfacing first with React's internal element constructs.
Option Two - Parsing
As you imply, it's heavy lifting. but libraries exist to parse HTML (which could be created or derived as a string from your intermediary object) into React constructs.
How useful this really is depends on use case.

The first option could work, but I'm not entirely sure if there are not some downsides to completely re-building the entire DOM (as setting the inner html would imply). It's not like I need a focused element to retain the focus or so, but I fear there may be some other issue like that lurking. As for the parsing, I already do parsing, but only for importing a document. That's why I have the attribute and style names in the wrong format.

Well, I guess the constraints here (unless I'm missing something, very possible), already imply "rebuild DOM" is inevitable. You have some intermediary object representation of that DOM. Wether you use DOM apis direct, or React to create it as real life dom objects (as dom elements are not natively serializable) leads to an inevitability of rebuilding it. Well -- if "rebuilding" means "instantiating". In option 1, innherhtml actually only sets a tiny dom element (very fast). A recursive op then appends to it.

All that said, definitely the question makes me wonder about the value of the intermediary abstraction.  Maybe the document parsing happens on the server? If so. life would be easier for it to actually bung a HTML representation straight to the browser with one canonical innerHTML call in the client to set the whole thing (actually very quick). But depends what you need. Seek alignment and try to see if middle abstractions are truly useful (maybe they are).

I'll go the hacking around the issues way for now. Having the classes and styles as more than just strings is beneficial anyway, and with camel-case/kebab-case conversion the remaining exceptions are few.

Right yeh. If youre building what i think you are -- a no code HTML solution -- this is indeed all a pretty hard problem fundamentally. For you to be able to leverage React's declarative model in a situation where markup comes from the outside, you're just gonna have to map into that model. With this framing, personally I would start to thinking about separating your "app layer" understanding of a model and the "concrete" HTML impl. Its unavoidable.

This would take the form of performing a conversion into this target model  you decide on -- and  relating to react attribute formats is reasonable as a sensible target -- on the server side. You want normalisation and to deal with a common model. You don't want to support an essentially uncontrolled model on an ongoing basis. I.e. they should import once, and that imported structure is then stored as a representation. It causes problems for you on a scale that  is unlikely to be valuable enough to solve. This sort of realisation is going to be crucial to make sure you don't spin your wheels!

No worries, I think for my case the workarounds are fine, I just wanted to check if there's a cleaner way. Thanks for the help!
